# Applying a bit mask based on a different mask

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitmask

A bit of a puzzle here.

I have a sequence of 4 bits, named **A**. It must be modified based on 2 masks: **B** and **C**. **B** is a mask telling us which bits of **A** are to be modified, and **C** tells us the value to apply on **A**. In my case **C** is always 1111 or 0000, but I would also be interested in a generic answer.

For example, let's start with:

```
A = 0000
B = 0001
C = 1111

// Then the result should be:
D = 0001
```

A less trivial example:

```
A = 0001
B = 1010
C = 1111

// Then the result should be:
D = 1011
```

And to showcase with a different **C**:

```
A = 1011
B = 0010
C = 0000

// Then the result should be:
D = 1001
```

What is the best (most concise, readable and effective) way to accomplish this in C++ using bitwise operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Binary `C`, readable version:

   ```
    if (C) {
        D = A | B; 
    } else {
        D = A & ~B;   
    }
   ```
2. Arbitrary `C`:

   First, we need to set those bits of `A` to `1` that equal to `1` in both `B` and `C`

   ```
   D = A | (B & C)
   ```

   Then we need to set those bits to `0` that equal to `1` in `B` and equal to `0` in `C`

   ```
   D = D & ~(B & ~C)
   ```

   or a bit simply

   ```
   D = D & (~B | C)
   ```

Comment: This seems good based on the fact that **C** will always be 0000 or 1111. But what if it was not? Say A=1011, B=0110, C=1100, and the result should be D=1101.

Comment: Then it is a different problem, with different solutions :-)

Comment: @AlexMillette - That's not what your original question says the problem is.

Comment: You're right and my problem is indeed solved. However I believe that it could help someone looking for the more generic answer.